# Ansible ask become for a specific host

Tags: ansible

I need to use the --ask-become-pass parameter for specific host and I would prefer If it could be done in an inventory file. Is this possible?

Some host require a password while other dont. So I dont want to add the --ask-become-pass when running a playbook. I only need for specfic hosts.

Comment: Have you tried to set the [Connection variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#connection-variables) in the inventory? There is no inventory alternative to *--ask-become-pass*. You should set static *ansible_become_pass* in inventory for hosts that need it.

Comment: I have tried adding ansible_ask_pass in the inventory to no avail. I dont want to add the password as it will differ for each user that runs the playbook

Comment: The standard scenario is: 1) user runs a playbook and connects with ssh to remote_user@host with the public key. 2) remote_user escalates the privilege to become_user. "A password  (ansible_become_pass) that will differ for each user that runs the playbook" doesn't make sense. See [Become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#id1).

Comment: step 2. the remote_user needs input his password to sudo to the become_user.

Comment: Sure, remote_user needs input his password to sudo to the become_user.  This password does not change for a particular user who connects with ssh to remote_user@host. Hence, "set static ansible_become_pass in inventory for hosts that need it". Do the users connect to various remote_user? Then the users need a various inventory, configured for example in *.ansible.cfg*.

Comment: cool, thanks for you assistance. For now I will just use the -K option.